# Google app engine generating very long id's with few records

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using google app engine for my application with objectify. All my tables and entities are creating properly, But the entity id is creating very long value even i am having 3 records in my DB. the id is like this 4785074604081152.

But in my previous projects with google app engine was generated very small numbers with one or two record.

Please clarify me!

Comment: Thats correct , it uses sparse id's to spread data across tablets.

Answer (score 3):

AppEngine changed recently to random ID numbers.  The change improves scalability.

Answer (score 1):

We use "scattered" ids to improved performance. That's hinted at in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Using_the_Datastore under "Specifying the Automatic ID Allocation Policy"